# Maximal Hausdorff dimension of the set on which derivatives do not agree

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Let $f, g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be functions that are differentiable a.e. with $f’ = g’$ almost everywhere. What is the maximal Hausdorff dimension $d$ (and corresponding Hausdorff $d$-measure) of the set on which $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable but $f’ \neq g’$?

Comment: Is there an obvious reason that the 'supremal' dimension should be achieved?

Comment: Using $h = f - g,$ the question becomes: If $h'$ exists a.e. and $h' = 0$ a.e., then what is supremum of the Hausdorff dimension of the set at which $h'$ exists and differs from zero? (Several versions, actually, depending on whether none or one or both of the $h'$ exists requirements include infinite derivatives.) Off-hand I don't know (probably $1$ even for the strongest version and with "a.e." replaced with "everywhere"), but my answer to [Set of zeroes of the derivative of a pathological function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155350/13130) may be of use. **(continued)**

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what possibilities exist for the Hausdorff dimension of sets belonging to Zahorski's $M_4$ class. Probably any dimension strictly less than $1$ is possible, but I don't know about achieving dimension $1.$

Comment: @DaveLRenfro If you can get any dimension less than one, can't you stitch these functions together to some $h: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ and reparametrise it via a diffeomorphism $(0,1) \to \mathbf{R}$? This would give dimension one, no?

Comment: @Keo Moos: Unless I'm overlooking something, what you suggest seems fine. In fact, I believe I made a similar comment about something similar (achieving maximal Hausdorff dimension for a single graph by gluing appropriate graphs) in a comment somewhere, probably MSE, within the last 2 or 3 years.

Answer (score 4):

If by not agree you include that the derivative may not exist, you can get any dimension and measure that does not contradict the almost everywhere. Consider the worst case $d=1$:

Take the construction of the Cantor-set. If in the $n$-th step you remove the middle $\frac{1}{n+1}$-th part of each interval, you get a set $C$ of Hausdorff-dimension $1$ but with $\mathcal{H}^1(C) =0$. So if you construct the Cantor-function using the same intervals, you get a function $f$ with $f'=0$ a.e, so for $g(x):=0$ you get $f'=g'$ a.e. except on $C$.

Comment: Right though this is the less interesting case... I would want them to both exist and not agree.

Comment: @NateRiver To be honest, I am struggling to come up with any example for that case. Allowing $\pm \infty$ as values for $f'$ you can do something with jumps, but apart from that, if there are any such functions, they probably need to be highly oscillating, i.e. not even in BV and that is outside of my expertise.

Answer (score -1):

If the derivatives exist for $x \in [0,1],$ then $f$ and $g$ must be continuous on some open set $A \subset [0,1].$ If $f \neq g$ on $A$ but $f' = g'$ a.e on $A$, then by integrating $f_1 = g_1 + C$, for some constant $C$ locally on open set $A$. However, because all the functions are continuous (locally on A) $f = g + C$ everywhere on $A$. Moreover, it's enough to consider the problem locally, if the derivatives exist. So the answer is $0,$ if the derivatives exist.

EDIT:(I now try to use FTC locally)

Comment: I don't think the FTC necessarily holds...

Comment: Continuous a.e. definitely does not imply continuous everywhere.

Comment: yes I am sorry, I will remove this answer.

Comment: The derivatives are only assumed to exist almost everywhere.

Comment: @LSpice True, but OP was interested just that case in a comment to an another answer